# ROSjava Maven3 error

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

## Hi all
I am getting an error when building rosjava (a lot of repeated stuff of the same format)

...
Int32MultiArray.java:[16,3] annotations are not supported in -source 1.3
(use -source 5 or higher to enable annotations)
@Override  public java.lang.String getDataType() { return __s_getDataType(); }

Int32MultiArray.java:[86,16] for-each loops are not supported in -source 1.3
(use -source 5 or higher to enable for-each loops)
for(int val : data) {

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Mar 19 10:06:14 EDT 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/88M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed!
Module directory not cleaned up: /tmp/tmpGNrvk1

====================================================================================

I've been told to change the default maven compiler from 1.4 to 1.5, but I have no idea where to do that (following this: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html)

Can someone explain what's going on here, and point me in the right direction? I'm somewhat new to maven.
Thanks much.

EDIT: fixed, had to update dependencies in gradle and add mavenLocal(), mavenCentral()

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29973/rosjava-maven3-error/) by [altherik](https://answers.ros.org/users/2006/altherik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-03-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the edited post:

Missing mavenLocal() and mavenCentral() repositories and dependencies in the build.gradle script.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0